# How to generate Signature for the AWS Import API request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, import

According to the AWS Import API docs the request looks like this:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8
host: https://importexport.amazonaws.com
content-length:356
Operation=CreateJob&Manifest=manifestVersion%3A%202.0%0Abucket%3A%20myBucket 
%0AaccessKeyId%3A%2013Q2729HYRYMYRB3FK02%0AreturnAddress%3A%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20 
Amazon.com%20ATTN%20Joe%20Random%20%0A%20%20%20%20street1%3A%201200%20AAAA%20Ave%20 
S.%0A%20%20%20%20city%3A%20Seattle%0A%20%20%20%20stateOrProvince%3A%20WA%0A%20%20%20%20 
postalCode%3A%2098114%0A%20%20%20%20phoneNumber%3A%20206-266-0000%0A%20%20%20%20 
country%3A%20USA&JobType=Import&AWSAccessKeyId=1111729HYRYMYRB3FK02& 
SignatureVersion=2&SignatureMethod=%2FVfkltRBOoSUi1sWxRzN8rw%3D
```

As you can see the last parameter in the body data is SignatureMethod. But it looks like Signature. I have found two available values for the SignatureMethod. They are HmacSHA1 and HmacSHA256.

I used the aws/s3 gem in order to generate the Signature query string and finally I've got the request looks like the previous one but with small change at the end.

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8
host: https://importexport.amazonaws.com
content-length:356

Operation=CreateJob&Manifest=manifestVersion%3A%202.0%0Abucket%3A%20myBucket 
%0AaccessKeyId%3A%2013Q2729HYRYMYRB3FK02%0AreturnAddress%3A%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20 
Amazon.com%20ATTN%20Joe%20Random%20%0A%20%20%20%20street1%3A%201200%20AAAA%20Ave%20 
S.%0A%20%20%20%20city%3A%20Seattle%0A%20%20%20%20stateOrProvince%3A%20WA%0A%20%20%20%20 
postalCode%3A%2098114%0A%20%20%20%20phoneNumber%3A%20206-266-0000%0A%20%20%20%20 
country%3A%20USA&JobType=Import&AWSAccessKeyId=1111729HYRYMYRB3FK02& 
SignatureVersion=2&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA1&Expires=2010-09-16T00:50:54-07:00&Signature=%2FVfkltRBOoSUi1sWxRzN8rw%3D
```

But the response is still 403 Forbidden.

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
x-amzn-RequestId: c0cb004b-c15e-11df-ad6c-5731ef5a3d54
Content-MD5: HvqVlJqxxJ5B5A73W4nUCg==
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 439
Date: Thu, 16 Sep 2010 06:50:55 GMT

<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://importexport.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-06-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>c0cb004b-c15e-11df-ad6c-5731ef5a3d54</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

You could find the code I used to test this here http://gist.github.com/581726

What's wrong and how can I generate the signature correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what this gem does, but a basic signing works like this:

```
aws_secret = 'foo' # aws provides this

query_string = 'Operation=CreateJob&Manifest=...' # this is for your api call

hmac = HMAC::SHA256.new(aws_secret)
hmac.update(query_string)
signature = Base64.encode64(hmac.digest).chomp
```

**BTW**: You should regenerate your credentials since you shared your access key on here.